# Problems with d3.scale.ordinal

Tags: javascript, charts, axis, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
var dados = [
    ["Brasil", 20], 
    ["Canadá", 31],
    ["Japão", 29],
    ["USA", 126],
    ["Inglaterra", 81],
    ["Nova Zelândia", 25],
    ["Turquia", 34]
];

dados.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });

/* Chart Area */
var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "grafico")
    .attr("width", 700)
    .attr("height",300);    

/* Define X-axis */
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dados)[1] ])
    .range([0, 500]);    

/* Define Y-axis */
var domainY = dados.map(function(d) {return d[0];})
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(domainY)
    .rangeBands([0, 300]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(0);

/* CALL Y-AXIS  */
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(120,0)");

/* DRAW BARS */
var bar = chart.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(dados)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(130,0)"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]);} )
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-6);
```

**MY QUESTION**

When I call Y-AXIS after draw BARS the `y.domain()` looks like this:

```
["USA", "Inglaterra", "Turquia", "Canadá", "Japão", "Nova Zelândia", "Brasil", 
Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
```

And the categories (Y-AXIS) are plotted in pairs NAME/VALUE:

```
 USA,126 
 Inglaterra,81
 Turquia, 34
 Canadá,31
 Japão,29
 Nova Zelândia,25
 Brasil,20
```

When I call Y-AXIS before draw BARS the `y.domain()` looks the same, but the categories are correctly plotted:

```
 USA 
 Inglaterra
 Turquia
 Canada
 Japão
 Nova Zelândia
 Brasil
```

I tried many changes on Domain without success.  The domainY looks correct but after binding data to chart the duplication occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're passing the wrong value to your y-scale. Instead of `attr("y", y)` you need to say `attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[0]); })`.

Comment: @mbostock : Sir y(d.y) return null value here is code http://jsfiddle.net/AmeetRana/EtEgx/4/ and also wrong y scale